# Oracle user_constraints view not showing all constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I need to get info about all Oracle metadata objects (such as constraints, indices and so on). When browsing the database with PL/SQL Developer, I am able to view and/or edit all objects of such kind. My objective is to get all this data programmatically from a desktop application.
**And here, the issue comes:**
When executing the query to `USER_CONSTRAINTS` I get only some of the constraints, but not all of them (I still can see them in PL/SQL Developer though). And the same situation occurs when I try to get data from `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` (I don't have access to `DBA_CONSTRAINTS`).
Can anyone help?

P.S. Problem solved
I tried filtering the `user_constraints` view by the constraints' names (and strangely didn't find them), but I was able to see them once I filtered by the names of tables that own them.
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: If SQL Developer shows them, they *are* available in `ALL_CONSTRANTS`. Please show us an example of a `create table` and your `select` where the constraint is not displayed.

Comment: Are you filtering in your queries? Like, for example, querying `all_constraints` but only `where owner = user`, or for certain constraint types?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, I will provide the DDL and selects just a little later, somethins urgent came up. Alex Poole, right now I am trying to work with foreign keys. So I am filtering the views with `TYPE='R'`. The next filter is `TABLE='table_name'`. And for both `user_constraints` and `all_constraints` the outcome is the same: some of the constraints don't show up in the result view, although I see them in PL/SQL Developer UI.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, where my constraints (and table) was not showing in the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` view. I then saw that my table was not visible to public, and that was why my other user could not see it.

The solution was executing

```
GRANT SELECT ON myTable TO public;
```